# Migrate MyISAM database with InnoDB and MyISAM tables to new server

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, myisam

I have a MyISAM database with MyISAM and InnoDB tables, I want to migrate this database to another server, For MyISAM simply copying the .frm .MYI and .MYD works but for the InnoDB tables how they can be moved to new server?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the configuration and versions are identical, and that the source server is completely shut down, you can move the `ibdata` file and all of the `*.frm` and `*.ibd` files. But it isn't advised.

The portable way to move all (or some) of the databases is to dump them using `mysqldump` and restore them on the target using `mysql`.